# Split API to use its part as a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using an API that has a lot of different possible calls. I want to change a part of it in VUE so that depending on a different button different call is made.

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=<>&language=en-US&page=1

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=<>&language=en-US&page=1

Here are two different API calls that are possible and I want to make it so that it looks something like this: 
"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" +variable+ "?api_key=<>&language=en-US&page=1"

and then depending on which button I pressed it would either make a call for "top_rated" or if another button is pressed it would be "upcoming"

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us the code?

Comment: What are you using to make the API call itself, like constructing a http GET? And what kind of data is expected to be received from the API?
Axios would be a good plugin for both, sending gets and handling posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String literal **` `** to insert dynamic value.

```
<button @click="apiCall(true)">Upcoming</button>
<button @click="apiCall(false)">Top Rated</button>
...
methods: {
  apiCall(isUpcoming) {
     const apiType = isUpcoming ? 'upcoming' : 'top_rated';
     const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${apiType}?api_key=<>&language=en-US&page=1`;
     // Fetch data with url.
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to archive this. Without the rest of the code I cannot suggest much.
Eventually you can create a method in your VUE component that returns the "top_rated" or "upconmig".

```html
<template>
  <button :href="'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + getAction + '/?yourqueryparams'"></button>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
        name: 'Movie DB',
        methods: {
          getAction: function(){
             return "top_rated"; //put condition here
          }
        }
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand your question, but maybe you need this:

vue template:

```
<button @click=handler('top_rated')>this is button no.1</button>
<button @click=handler('upcoming')>this is button no.2</button>
```

javascript:

```
methods: {
  handler(type) {
    const url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + type + "?api_key=<>&language=en-US&page=1"
    return fetch(url)
  }
}
```

Comment: `@click=handler('top_rated')` should be `@click="handler('top_rated')"`. :)

Comment: Sorry my friend, anyway, you got me